# Is there a way to add a new constructors to hooked sort Int?

Tags: kframework

I'm trying to migrate a semantic made with the version: `K tool, version 3.6` *(yeah...)*.
We have this rule:

```
syntax Int
       ::= #cint(Int,Int)
```

and when I compile the semantic with the K version: `5.1.16` and the LLVM backend, I get this error:

```
[Error] Compiler: Cannot add new constructors to hooked sort Int
```

Is there a way to support this rule with the version `5.1.16` ?

Comment: It's not supported. We'll need to know more about your use-case to suggest alternatives. What does `#cint` represent?

Comment: The thing is that I do not know either what was the use-case.
So I removed the code and the project seems to still work.
I think that was a dead code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The backends don't support extending the hooked sorts.

But you can use macros to bypass it:

```
$ cat test.k
module TEST
    imports INT
    configuration <k> one +Int 2 </k>
    syntax Int ::= "one"
    rule one => 1 [macro]
endmodule
$ kompile test.k
$ krun
<k>
  3 ~> .
</k>
```

Macros are handled in the front-end, and as long as you process all your constructors that way, you can get away with extending the hooked sorts.